# Today is Thursday. Is "next" Saturday the day after tomorrow or nine days away?

Tags: phrases

Some people are telling me the day after tomorrow is "*this* Saturday", and "*next* Saturday" is a week later.  To others, "this Saturday" is synonymous with "next Saturday".

A few people claim that "this Saturday" is synonymous with "last Saturday", but I am reasonably certain those people are nuts.

Comment: If it were only Sunday or Monday, you might get away with saying "next Saturday" meaning the next one that comes, but if it's already Thursday, you'd definitely say "this Saturday" because it is nearly at hand.  Some of your friends are being pedantic and/or captious. See this other recent question:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224617/person-who-pretends-to-not-understand-unless-one-speaks-in-exactly-the-words-the